# Intel vs GCC on constexpr

Tags: c++, gcc, intel, static-members, constexpr

The following code compiles ok with Intel-2015 but fails with gcc 4.8.3
Who is right?

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int const& x ) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }

struct S
{
    static constexpr int ce = 42;
};

int main()
{
    f(S::ce);

    return 0;
}
```

g++ error:

```
/tmp/ccOIxa2V.o: In function `main':
test_constexpr.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `S::ce'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: GCC's right. It's correct to use `s.se` but `std::cout`

Comment: `ce` is static, `s::ce` is right. It has to do with `constexpr`

Comment: @ForceBru, The dot operator works on objects, not types.

Comment: @user2052436, why are u using GCC but not g++? That's C++ isn't it?

Comment: @ForceBru, GCC is the GNU Compiler Collection. It includes gcc and g++, which are C and C++ compilers respectively.

Comment: @ForceBru: Actually you can compile C++ source with `gcc` just fine. You need to manually link the C++ standard library, though (`-lstdc++`).

Comment: Both are right. This is an ODR violation that does not require a diagnostic.

Comment: @chris, I meant something like `S test; test.ce;`. My previous comment was pretty silly :)

Comment: What does Intel compiler with this code? The `f` function gets inlined? If it is not inlined, then how the reference is passed? I saw similar problem with gcc when using -fno-inline parameter.

Comment: @ibre5041 I am not sure what icc does. I use only one flag: `-std=c++11`. How can I find out if it inlined the function?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. Use `-c` to only compile the source and to create obj `.o` file. The use `nm` to dump symbols in it and `objdump` to disassemble it. I guess that no text is generated for the `f` function and its code is directly inlined into the `main` function. You can also try to use option `-fno-inline` and `-O0` (no optimalizations) for Intel compiler and see what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the function `f` takes a reference argument, there has to be a definition of `S::ce` that a reference can point to at runtime; the compiler can't just replace the argument with a literal 42.  So you have to add an out-of-class definition:

```
const int S::ce;
```

just like you would with a non-`constexpr` variable.  This allocates a memory location for the value at runtime, for use by references and other things that couldn't be computed at compile time.

See [this GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50785) (which has comments explaining why it isn't actually a bug) for more information.

Comment: Just checked: if I add out-of-class `const int test::ce;` as you suggested, icc works and g++ fails with `error: redeclaration 'S::ce'`. If I add `constexpr int test::ce;`, then both work.

Comment: Oops, sorry about the `test::` thing — I'd copied code from a test program without actually checking it back against your question.  But `const int S::ce;` works for me; you shouldn't need `constexpr` in the out-of-class definition.

Comment: It works for me if `S::ce` is declared as `const`. But if it is declared as `constexpr`, then out-of-class definition has to be `constexpr` as well. Otherwise, both icc and g++ fail. I.e., definition and declaration must match exactly, cannot have `const` at one place and `constexpr` at the other.
Is it different for your compiler version?

Answer (score 4):

I think GCC is right. BTW, CLang 3.5.1 gives the same error.

The thing is that constant static variables are allowed not to be defined only if their address is not taken and they are not bound to references.

Your example bounds a reference to it, so the explicit definition is needed.

From the C++11 draft (9.4.2.3), conveniently edited:

> A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class definition with the constexpr specifier; [...] The member shall still be defined in a namespace scope if it is odr-used (3.2) in the program [...].

And in 3.2:

> A variable [...] whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied.

That lvalue-to-rvalue conversion stuff is, roughly speaking, done everytime the variable is used except when binding a reference or as argument to the unary take-address operator `&`.

Comment: Can we be so bold as to say that `static` in-class declarations have an implicit `extern` in front of them?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Generally speaking, yes, static member declarations have external linkage.